# get admin_creator of a post Facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the userid of the person who creates the post, and based on the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post#read

This information is in the admin_creator field. Example:  `{post-id}?fields=admin_creator` I am already the admin of the page and `manage_pages` permission, so I dont understand what is going on... Thanks!

Comment: That is the documentation for a scheduled post.

Comment: You are right. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

you must be an administrator for the page.

Answer (score 0):

{post-id} must be a scoped id.
like this : 618683548311391_851244161721994

Comment: yes, i know. I do not have any problem to request post. My problem is, that the admin_creator field is not displayed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{page_id}/posts?fields=admin_creator&access_token={page_access_token}
```

PS: This endpoint requires an access_token from the page